# Moving map-embedded annotation to a different annotation group

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, annotation

I'm working with an annotation group that was generated by converting labels to annotation and storing it in the map instead of a database.  After this conversion, the scale of the map was changed, and a number of edits were made to the annotations.

I needed to duplicate a few of the annotations to indicate parts of some multi-part polygons that originally only had one label for each part.  When I copied and pasted an existing label in the annotation group, however, I made the mistake of placing it in the Default annotation group instead of the one I was editing.

Since the Default group has a reference scale fixed to the data frame, the pasted annotations are a much different size than the original annotations.  Is there a way to move annotation from one annotation group to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been awhile, but if I'm not mistaken you can select annotations from one group and paste them in a target group.  In other words, from the default group select the ones you intended for a different target, right-click and copy (or cut), then change the group target to the one intended and paste.  I'd copy them if cut is not an option, or at least to make sure the behavior is what you expect when you paste...then you can go back and delete the copied annos in the default you copied from.  Like I said, haven't tried this lately, but I think you can only select annos from the active group, so you have to switch out the active group in the anno toolbar.

Yes here:

Using cut and paste to move text between annotation groups
(Desktop » Mapping » Adding text to a map » Displaying annotation and graphic text)
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s80000001q000000